# MacWire: Is it possible to get automatic wiring of recursively dependent case classes, as in @Inject with Guice?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, macwire

The following code fails at compile time:

```
object Foo {
  case class A()
  case class B(a: A)
  case class C(b: B)

  lazy val a = wire[A]
  // Error:(14, 22) Cannot find a value of type: [QuickMain.B]
  lazy val c = wire[C]
}
```

Is it possible to get macwire to automatically infer that it can create a `B` by creating an `A` (Honestly, `lazy val a = wire[A]` shouldn't even be necessary)? If macwire can't do it, is there another Scala framework that can do it in a *typesafe* manner (I know of Dagger, but I'm looking for a scala-based solution).

To illustrate, in Guice I could do the following:

```
public class JavaExample {
  public static class A {}

  public static class B {
    @Inject
    public B(A a) {}
  }

  public static class C {
    @Inject
    public C(B b) {}
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // No bindings necessary!
    var injector = Guice.createInjector();
    System.out.println(injector.getInstance(C.class));
  }
}
```